# How to deal with `module.scss` with react and next?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I am very lost.

For context, I am using Next and React.

```
// package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@netlify/plugin-nextjs": "^3.4.2",
    "next": "^10.0.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.11.2",
    "react-svg": "14.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "sass": "^1.34.0"
  }
```

I use `npx next build && npx next start -p 4000` to test production locally. It all works fine in dev using `netlify dev -e`.

There are weird effects. When I have two imports of `.module.scss`, the client-side javascript just stops.

I have a page:

```
// /pages/test.js
import CompA from 'components/comp-a'
import CompB from 'components/comp-b'
```

And:

```
// /components/comp-a.js
import styles from 'components/comp-a.module.scss`
```

and

```
// /components/comp-b.js
import styles from 'components/comp-b.module.scss`
```

This situation renders correctly visually but **NO** client-side javascript is working at all and, of course, without any error. I spent the day commenting and uncommenting each component and line of my source code to narrow down to this situation.

I tried by commenting out in the `page`, with one component the client-side js works, not with two.

I tried commenting out the `styles` import in one of the components, the client-side js works as well.

Another situation where it does not work is :

```
// components/comp-a.js
import styles from 'components/comp-a.module.js'
import CompB from 'components/comp-b.module.js'
```

and it works if I comment either one of the style or the sub component.

And none of it makes sense because in the page, I also have the `Layout` being imported that does contain its own `styles` and that works fine.

What is going on ???

Edit:
Continuing to dig, I found out that I was doing `@extend .class-abc` and at the top `@import 'style/foo.module';` , and the `.class-abc` was containing an other class:

```
// /style/foo.module.scss
.class-abc {
  ...
  .bar { 
    ...
  }
}
```

For some reason, commenting out `.bar` solve the problem. No idea what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

One of the main benefits of using css/scss modules is that you keep the styles close to the component and everything gets namespaced for you. So you wouldn't typically import the `component` styles into your `page`. Restructuring a bit should help:

```
- components/
  - comp-a/
    - index.js
    - index.module.scss
  - comp-b/
    - index.js
    - index.module.scss
- pages
  // If test.js doesn't also have its own styles
  - test.js
  // Or if test.js has its own css/scss modules
  - test
    - index.js
    - index.module.scss
```

Your components and pages would then look like this:

```js
// comp-a
import styles from "./index.module.css"

export default function MyCompA() {
  return (<div className={styles.someClass}>I have local comp-a styles</div>)
}

// comp-b
import styles from "./index.module.css"

export default function MyCompB() {
  return (<div className={styles.someClass}>I have local comp-b styles</div>)
}

// test
import MyCompA from "../components/comp-a"
import MyCompB from "../components/comp-b"

// If this also has its own styles
import styles from "./index.module.scss"

export default function MyCompTestPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <p className={styles.someClass}>I have local test page styles</p>
      <MyCompA />
      <MyCompB />
    </>
  )
}
```

#### Sharing Styles Between Components

If multiple components need to share the same styles, you would generally want to (a) extract those styles to a global stylesheet or (b) extract that common code into its own component or (c) share the stylesheet between components. An example of option c can look like this:

```
- components/
  - comps-ab/
    - comp-a.js
    - comp-b.js
    - index.module.scss
- pages
  - test.js
```

```js
// comps-ab/comp-a
import styles from "./index.module.css"

export default function MyCompA() {
  return (<div className={styles.someClass}>I have shared comps-ab styles but still local to these components</div>)
}

// comps-ab/comp-b
import styles from "./index.module.css"

export default function MyCompB() {
  return (<div className={styles.someClass}>I have shared comps-ab styles but still local to these components</div>)
}

// test
import MyCompA from "../components/comps-ab/comp-a"
import MyCompB from "../components/comps-ab/comp-b"

export default function MyCompTestPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <MyCompA />
      <MyCompB />
    </>
  )
}
```

In this case, your two components pull from the same stylesheet, but it's still local to those two components and isn't brought into the `test.js` page manually.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing. But `CompA` was reusing a similar but different enough structure from `CompB`, how can I make it so I don't have to copy paste all the CSS ? My solution was to import `compb.module.scss` into `CompA`

Comment: If there's that much crossover between the two, then you would either (a) move those common styles to a global stylesheet or (b) extract those common pieces into a separate component with its own styles so `CompA` and `CompB` call the new `CompC` which has its own shared styles.

Comment: Also, you don't need to only have one component per folder. If `CompA` and `CompB` share the same styles with only a few changes, then you could import the same stylesheet into both. I'll update the answer to show this.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why error in the scss system block the client-side javascript. Is there a way to debug the compilation of the scss ?

Comment: usually, the errors in client-side CSS come from the hashed names (for caching). Are the class names being appended with random hashes?

Comment: Yes they are but there are no visual error. All the CSS is good. But the client-side javascript do not work. When I comment out enough of the CSS then it works again.